# Wordpress 4.1: Custom Post Type won't load, links don't work

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have registered a custom post type:

```
<?php
register_post_type( 'my_cpt_fiction',
  array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Custom Posts' )
      , 'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Post' )
      , 'add_new' => 'Add New'
      , 'add_new_item' => 'Create a new Custom Post'
      , 'edit' => 'Edit Custom Post'
      , 'edit_item' => 'Edit Custom Post'
      , 'new_item' => 'Create a new Custom Post,'
      , 'view_item' => 'View Custom Post,'
      , 'search_items' => 'Search Custom Post'
      , 'not_found' => 'No Custom Posts found'
      , 'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Custom Posts found in trash'
    ),
      'public' => true
    , 'has_archive' => true

    , 'supports' => Array(
        'title' => 'title'
      , 'editor' => 'editor'
      , 'author' => 'author'
      , 'comments' => 'comments'
    )
    , 'show_ui'             => true
    , 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' =>  'my_custom_post' , 'with_front' => false, 'feeds' => true )
    , 'capability_type'    => array('my_custom_post','my_custom_posts')
    , 'map_meta_cap'        => true
    , 'taxonomies' => array('category')
    , 'publicly_queryable'  => true
    , 'exclude_from_search' => false
    , 'query_var'          => true
  )
);
```

I have no taxonomies.

This added to the menu, I can create and edit. But when I visit the link to the custom post, it doesn't load, instead I see the main static home page.

I have tried many different combinations of permalinks, or no permalinks.

I also cannot seem to find any information about specifically showing a custom post type AS IF it were a post or page, people just assume it must work...

Any help would be appreciated.

/J

Answer (score 4):

This happens most of the time because of the WordPress rewrite rules, they are stored on Database and you need to flush them.

Go to Settings - Permalinks and just click save so you initiate flush rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in the init hook:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_type' );
function create_my_post_type() {
    // Your code here
}
```

After creating the post type or changing it's rewrite settings, head over to your wordpress settings->permalinks and click save. This will reset your rewrite rules and recreate the .htaccess file.